# I'm trying to automatically allocate memory for N structs in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a text file that I am currently copying and pasting into my console with the first line being the number of structs that I have to create, and then each successive three lines are the three pieces of data I'm trying to put into my structs.  Is it possible to properly allocate memory for N structs (each with one string and two floats), and then have them stored so I can access and sort them later in MIPS?  I'm having a ton of trouble grasping my head around the problem.

Thanks for any advice.  I would add code, but I don't really even know where to start yet.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and assume you are using GNU AS assembler. If that is the assembler, I'd suggest [reading the documentation](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/Pseudo-Ops.html#Pseudo%20Ops), in particular [.comm](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/Comm.html#Comm) and [.struct](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.12/as.info/Struct.html#Struct). The `.comm` directive allocates uninitialized data memory. The `.struct` directive allows you to create symbols that represent structure offsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running under some sort of operating system or other environment that provides memory management, you can use those services to allocate memory dynamically (such as the `sbrk` system call in SPIM).

Otherwise (size permitting) the easiest way is to use the stack by adjusting the stack pointer: `subu $sp, $sp, $t0` would allocate `$t0` bytes on the stack. Make sure `$t0` is a multiple of the word size (4) and that you release this memory when no longer needed. Caveat: the allocated block is in the frame of the current function, as such you can't return it to the caller (but can pass it down to called functions).